# Guidance on the most effective way to learn Sharepoint

Tags: 2010, learning

I am a .NET developer with a few years of experience in Winforms, WPF and some ASP.NET with C#. What would be the best way for me to go about learning sharepoint, as a developer? I would be Learning on my spare time, My work currently has nothing to do with sharepoint, but I have seen a bit of what sharepoint can do and I felt that It is a technology worth investing my time in.

I am interested In books, videos, possible training, webcasts, videos, blogs, forums, communities and any advice you may have.

Answer (score 4):

First suggestion is to learn how to Google. It's *the* most important tool a SharePoint developer has. For example, a search for "most effective way to learn sharepoint" would have pointed you to several worthwhile resources on the topic.

Since I'm here, I'll point you to a blog post I put together: [Getting Started with SharePoint 2010 Development–Links and Resources](http://msmvps.com/blogs/windsor/archive/2011/08/01/getting-started-with-sharepoint-2010-development-links-and-resources.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Since you have had experience with MS Technologies, I would suggest you visit:

[MSDN SharePoint Developer Training](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/aa905692)

It has more than enough information to get you started.